# How to reference an xml file from resources? Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, resources, filepath

I'm parsing in an xml file using `SAX` and need to add it as a resource instead of hard coding the file path.

I set up the file path y using a string like this:

```
private static final String GAME_FILE = "game.xml";
```

Its been suggested to use `getResourceAsStream` but I'm not sure how to apply that to my solution.

Does anyone how the reference the file from resources instead within the project?

This is how I reference the xml file by just adding it to the root of the project, which is bad practice:

```
public class Parser extends DefaultHandler{
    private static final String GAME_FILE = "game.xml";

    //You should have a boolean switch for each XML element, but not attribute
    boolean location = false;
    boolean description = false;
    boolean item = false;
    boolean gameCharacter = false;
    boolean searchAlgorithm = false;

    //Read in the XML file game.xml and use the current object as the SAX event handler
    public void parse() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        XMLReader xmlReader = null;
        SAXParserFactory spfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spfactory.setValidating(false);
        SAXParser saxParser = spfactory.newSAXParser();
        xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
        InputSource source = new InputSource(GAME_FILE);
        xmlReader.parse(source);
        xmlReader.setErrorHandler(this);
    }
```

Below shows the project structure after adding the file to a resources folder, but adding it to the resources folder, causes the file to not be found.

[image: resources location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that game.xml is technically in the "resources" packages. Thus using

```
GAME_FILE = "/resources/game.xml"
InputSource source = new InputSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(GAME_FILE));
```

should do the trick